# Approximately how many positive integer pairs (m,n) satisfies $m^2+n^2<2500$.

Tags: number-theory

Approximately how many positive integer pairs (m,n) satisfies $m^2+n^2<2500$.

---

For m=0, there are 50 integer n satisfies, so when m=50, none of n satisfies.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for $(m,n)$ to be inside a circle of radius $50$.  There is one point per square unit.  What is the area of the circle?  The exact number is the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem), which is hard, but you asked for an approximation, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It Represent a Inner part of Circle $(m-0)^2+(n-0)^2=(50)^2$, whose center is at

$(0,0)$ and Radius is $ = 50$

So First we will calculate Integer ordered pairs $(m,n)$ in $\bf{1^{st}}$ Quadrant and Multiply It by $4$ ,

bcz of $\bf{4}$ Quadrant and Then calculate for $\bf{X-axis}$ and $\bf{Y-axis}$ and also count $(0,0)$

So For $\bf{I^{st}}$ Quadrant::

Given $m^2+n^2 <2500\Rightarrow n<\sqrt{2500-m^2}$

Put integer values of $m$ for which $n$ is an Integer.